# JSPM - jspm install gives error "Registry not found"

Tags: javascript, node.js, aurelia, systemjs, jspm

Recently i started playing with aurelia-framework and so far so good but when i edited config.js to add some of my files that are not installed via jspm things worked fine i was importing my scripts no errors but when i cloned to another machine and run jspm install it fails cause it does't like that i have other paths other than npm and github in my config.js

**Configjs**

```
paths: {
    "*": "dist/*",
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*",
    "lib:*": "lib/*",
    "styles:*": "styles/*"
},

map: {
    "app-styles": "styles:app-styles",
    "uisearch": "lib:uisearch/uisearch@1.0.0",
    "component": "lib:component/component",
    "classie": "lib:classie/classie@2.0.0",
    "material": "lib:material/material",
    "ripples": "lib:ripples/ripples",
    "bootstrap-select": "lib:bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select@1.7.2"
    other deps...
}
```

**Error Message**

> err  Registry lib not found.
>
> err  Unable to load registry lib
>
> warn Installation changes not saved.

Please help am new to this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid making changes to the map section of your config.js by hand.  Instead use the jspm command line interface to add packages.  The jspm CLI will maintain your config.js for you.  For example, to add `classie` to your project you would execute the following:

```
jspm install npm:desandro-classie
```

More information at [jspm.io](http://jspm.io/).

**Note:** you don't need to edit the config.js to enable importing javascript/css that is part of your project.

If I'm interpreting your original post correctly you have a lib folder containing a ripples subfolder which has a ripples.js file inside of it.  You could access this "ripples" module like this:

```js
import ripples from 'lib/ripples/ripples';

ripples.foo();
...
```

Comment: what if the package i want simply does not exist on either npm or github? :)

Comment: True true, and to add on you should delete your config.js and recreate it with `jspm install`

Comment: @BeyondProgramming Then how do you expect `jspm` to be able to find it?  You have to use something that `jspm` knows about or create a JSPM package

Comment: config.js use is exclusive for jspm use only? if so what should i use for such a situation in aurelia cause i thought that config.js was a SystemJS thing or is it the same.